# Как сделать свечение вокруг SVG иконки?

Tags: css

[image: Пример]

Как создать свечение вокруг иконки SVG?
Иконка SVG будет являться ссылкой, то есть hover работает только в рамках этой иконки. Форма иконки сложная (не квадрат или груг).
Иконка то же должна менять цвет при наведении.

Comment: css filter drop-shadow

Comment: и как узнать , как выглядит ваш SVG ?

Comment: Да, я думаю, что box-shadow оптимальный вариант. Единственно получается, что его нужно применить не к иконке так она имеет размер в рамках своего содержания, а к родителю. Интересно было бы узнать можно ли сделать свечение отталкиваясь от формы или же нужно делать только грубо говоря отталкиваясь от точки за объектом? И я так понимаю нельзя сделать свечение в два направления одновременно?

Comment: Для примера подойдёт любая непростая форма.

Comment: @Agestor, я сказал не box-shadow, а drop-shadow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если цвет подсветки должен зависить от цвета картинки, то можно дважды положить эту картинку (одну поверх другой) и нижнюю заблюрить:

```css
svg {
  height: 8em;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
}

div > svg:first-child {
  filter: blur(16px);
  overflow: visible;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"><g transform="translate(0 -1028.4)"><path d="m3.1875 6l-2 10h2v-7h18v7h2l-2-10h-18z" fill="#f39c12" transform="translate(0 1028.4)"/><path d="m3.1875 1037.4-2 14h2 18 2l-2-14h-18z" fill="#e67e22"/><path d="m9 1030.4v5h-3v0.9 0.1h0.0312l5.9688 6.5 5.969-6.5 0.031-0.1v-0.9h-3v-5h-6z" fill="#2c3e50"/><path d="m1.1875 1044.4v7h22v-7h-8.188c-0.416 1.1-1.511 2-2.812 2-1.302 0-2.3975-0.9-2.813-2h-8.1875z" fill="#f1c40f"/><rect fill="#f39c12" height="1" width="22" x="1.1875" y="1051.4"/><path d="m9 0v1 5.9688h-3l6 6.5312 6-6.5312h-3v-5.9688-1h-6z" fill="#34495e" transform="translate(0 1028.4)"/></g></svg>
<div>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"><g transform="translate(0 -1028.4)"><path d="m3.1875 6l-2 10h2v-7h18v7h2l-2-10h-18z" fill="#f39c12" transform="translate(0 1028.4)"/><path d="m3.1875 1037.4-2 14h2 18 2l-2-14h-18z" fill="#e67e22"/><path d="m9 1030.4v5h-3v0.9 0.1h0.0312l5.9688 6.5 5.969-6.5 0.031-0.1v-0.9h-3v-5h-6z" fill="#2c3e50"/><path d="m1.1875 1044.4v7h22v-7h-8.188c-0.416 1.1-1.511 2-2.812 2-1.302 0-2.3975-0.9-2.813-2h-8.1875z" fill="#f1c40f"/><rect fill="#f39c12" height="1" width="22" x="1.1875" y="1051.4"/><path d="m9 0v1 5.9688h-3l6 6.5312 6-6.5312h-3v-5.9688-1h-6z" fill="#34495e" transform="translate(0 1028.4)"/></g></svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"><g transform="translate(0 -1028.4)"><path d="m3.1875 6l-2 10h2v-7h18v7h2l-2-10h-18z" fill="#f39c12" transform="translate(0 1028.4)"/><path d="m3.1875 1037.4-2 14h2 18 2l-2-14h-18z" fill="#e67e22"/><path d="m9 1030.4v5h-3v0.9 0.1h0.0312l5.9688 6.5 5.969-6.5 0.031-0.1v-0.9h-3v-5h-6z" fill="#2c3e50"/><path d="m1.1875 1044.4v7h22v-7h-8.188c-0.416 1.1-1.511 2-2.812 2-1.302 0-2.3975-0.9-2.813-2h-8.1875z" fill="#f1c40f"/><rect fill="#f39c12" height="1" width="22" x="1.1875" y="1051.4"/><path d="m9 0v1 5.9688h-3l6 6.5312 6-6.5312h-3v-5.9688-1h-6z" fill="#34495e" transform="translate(0 1028.4)"/></g></svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот так:

```css
.icon:hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px red);
}
.icon:hover path {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg x="0px" y="0px" viewbox="0 0 478.2 478.2" width="100" height="100" class="icon">
  <path d="M457.575,325.1c9.8-12.5,14.5-25.9,13.9-39.7c-0.6-15.2-7.4-27.1-13-34.4c6.5-16.2,9-41.7-12.7-61.5    c-15.9-14.5-42.9-21-80.3-19.2c-26.3,1.2-48.3,6.1-49.2,6.3h-0.1c-5,0.9-10.3,2-15.7,3.2c-0.4-6.4,0.7-22.3,12.5-58.1    c14-42.6,13.2-75.2-2.6-97c-16.6-22.9-43.1-24.7-50.9-24.7c-7.5,0-14.4,3.1-19.3,8.8c-11.1,12.9-9.8,36.7-8.4,47.7    c-13.2,35.4-50.2,122.2-81.5,146.3c-0.6,0.4-1.1,0.9-1.6,1.4c-9.2,9.7-15.4,20.2-19.6,29.4c-5.9-3.2-12.6-5-19.8-5h-61    c-23,0-41.6,18.7-41.6,41.6v162.5c0,23,18.7,41.6,41.6,41.6h61c8.9,0,17.2-2.8,24-7.6l23.5,2.8c3.6,0.5,67.6,8.6,133.3,7.3    c11.9,0.9,23.1,1.4,33.5,1.4c17.9,0,33.5-1.4,46.5-4.2c30.6-6.5,51.5-19.5,62.1-38.6c8.1-14.6,8.1-29.1,6.8-38.3    c19.9-18,23.4-37.9,22.7-51.9C461.275,337.1,459.475,330.2,457.575,325.1z M48.275,447.3c-8.1,0-14.6-6.6-14.6-14.6V270.1    c0-8.1,6.6-14.6,14.6-14.6h61c8.1,0,14.6,6.6,14.6,14.6v162.5c0,8.1-6.6,14.6-14.6,14.6h-61V447.3z M431.975,313.4    c-4.2,4.4-5,11.1-1.8,16.3c0,0.1,4.1,7.1,4.6,16.7c0.7,13.1-5.6,24.7-18.8,34.6c-4.7,3.6-6.6,9.8-4.6,15.4c0,0.1,4.3,13.3-2.7,25.8    c-6.7,12-21.6,20.6-44.2,25.4c-18.1,3.9-42.7,4.6-72.9,2.2c-0.4,0-0.9,0-1.4,0c-64.3,1.4-129.3-7-130-7.1h-0.1l-10.1-1.2    c0.6-2.8,0.9-5.8,0.9-8.8V270.1c0-4.3-0.7-8.5-1.9-12.4c1.8-6.7,6.8-21.6,18.6-34.3c44.9-35.6,88.8-155.7,90.7-160.9    c0.8-2.1,1-4.4,0.6-6.7c-1.7-11.2-1.1-24.9,1.3-29c5.3,0.1,19.6,1.6,28.2,13.5c10.2,14.1,9.8,39.3-1.2,72.7    c-16.8,50.9-18.2,77.7-4.9,89.5c6.6,5.9,15.4,6.2,21.8,3.9c6.1-1.4,11.9-2.6,17.4-3.5c0.4-0.1,0.9-0.2,1.3-0.3    c30.7-6.7,85.7-10.8,104.8,6.6c16.2,14.8,4.7,34.4,3.4,36.5c-3.7,5.6-2.6,12.9,2.4,17.4c0.1,0.1,10.6,10,11.1,23.3    C444.875,295.3,440.675,304.4,431.975,313.4z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Благодарю! Но этот вариант точно не подойдёт, получается обратная тень в области значка, а нужно, чтобы на большeю область вокруг значка. То есть получается должна быть привязка к родителю. <div class="fon"><div class="icon"></div></div>

Comment: Можете показать пример? Не понимаю о чем речь.

Comment: Вот это? https://codepen.io/shugich/pen/JNVEvP

Comment: Или вот это? https://codepen.io/shugich/pen/vmMgaX

Comment: У меня также возникала квадратная рамка ненужная вокруг SVG. Вот и стало интересно как избежать этого. Подозреваю тут либо делать масками, либо вовсе не отталкиваться от формы иконки. Вопрос обновил с картинкой.

Comment: Так, какая именно появляется квадратная рамка? По-хорошему, выложите свою реализацию, чтобы можно было увидеть что не так в вашем коде.

Comment: Ну та же самая, что в вашем ответе. Свечение должно заходить за рамки квадрата иконки. Вывод: свечение должно делать на уровне блока родителя в котором лежит иконка.

Comment: @Agestor, я исправил.

Comment: @shugich, почему откат?

Comment: @Qwertiy потому что это не решает проблему :-)

Comment: @shugich, overflow как раз решает проблему "квадратной рамки". А отступ у body был для большей наглядности.

Answer (score 3):

Если свечение одноцветное, то можно использовать css-фильтр `drop-shadow`:

```css
svg + svg {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 8px red);
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<svg height="150" width="150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><linearGradient id="s"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#e0ded2"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#cac6b2"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="r"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#6cb5ec"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#5eaeea"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="q"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#1c87d8"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#3197e4"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="i"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#a8815a"/><stop offset=".5" stop-color="#90704c"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#725433"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="j"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#473726"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#6f553a"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="a"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="d"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#97744f"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#866746"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="f"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#c7ae95"/><stop offset=".5" stop-color="#b69775"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#a57f57"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="c"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#8c6b49"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#6d5339"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="g"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#b08e69"/><stop offset=".5" stop-color="#9e7a53"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#906f4c"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="h"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#bb9d7d"/><stop offset=".5" stop-color="#ab865f"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#9f7a53"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="e"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#755a3d"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#a58057"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="m"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#b1b1b1" stop-opacity="0"/><stop offset=".5" stop-color="#b1b1b1"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#b1b1b1" stop-opacity="0"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="l"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#b3b3b3"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#9c9c9c"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="k"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#f4f4f4"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#cfcfcf"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="o"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#bdb295"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#c6bca3"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="n"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#ada07b"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#b7ab8b"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="p"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#c3ba9f"/><stop offset=".2" stop-color="#cec6b1"/><stop offset=".8" stop-color="#cec6b1"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#cdc5ae"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="b"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#ada07b"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#b7ab8b"/></linearGradient><linearGradient gradientTransform="translate(0 -164.655)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="t" x1="300.756" x2="328.975" xlink:href="#k" y1="560.903" y2="560.903"/><linearGradient gradientTransform="matrix(1.07445 0 0 1.2634 -24.445 -314.456)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="u" x1="306.859" x2="312.997" xlink:href="#l" y1="566.929" y2="559.842"/><linearGradient gradientTransform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 657.192 -164.655)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="v" x1="300.756" x2="328.975" xlink:href="#k" y1="560.903" y2="560.903"/><linearGradient gradientTransform="matrix(1.0951 0 0 1.30604 -31.23 -338.7)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="w" x1="346.751" x2="343.683" xlink:href="#l" y1="568.701" y2="559.842"/><linearGradient gradientTransform="translate(0 -164.655)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="x" x1="325.271" x2="331.408" xlink:href="#m" y1="563.386" y2="563.386"/></defs><path d="M18.74 44.95l52.153 30.014V145L18.74 114.985z" fill="#da2153"/><path d="M131.74 39.946L70.892 74.964V145l60.846-35.05z" fill="#fa2c64"/><path d="M14.456 42.673L79.916 5l55.628 32.693-64.555 37.27z" fill="#f44676"/><path d="M95.197 130.87V74.962l16.065-9.18v55.905z" fill="#ececec"/><path d="M131.51 40.07L70.88 74.946c-.027 6.222-.04 12.44.123 18.66l60.506-34.948z" fill="#9d2646" fill-opacity=".392"/><path d="M38.712 126.21V70.305l12.104 6.988V133.2z" fill="#ececec"/><path d="M18.54 44.81l.08 13.96-.08 4.546 4 2.312 48.45 27.97-.11-18.652z" fill="#66192d" fill-opacity=".392"/><path d="M135.544 37.74L70.88 74.946v13.93l.123.08 64.54-37.287z" fill="#fa376c"/><path d="M14.504 42.48V56.33L70.88 88.875v-13.93z" fill="#df2a5a"/><path d="M95.197 74.963V60.987L115.37 49.34v13.976z" fill="#ececec"/><path d="M50.816 77.293V63.316L34.676 54v13.975z" fill="#f2f2f2"/><path d="M34.677 54l64.555-37.272 16.138 9.318-64.554 37.27z" fill="#ececec"/><path d="M95.197 60.987L38.712 28.375l20.173-11.647L115.37 49.34z" fill="#f2f2f2"/><path d="M306.022 381.536c-12.115 0-12.732 11.06-8.368 15.423 2.63 2.63 6.13 4.97 9.852 4.97v.375l20.834 1.74v-7.086l-18.412-14.174c-1.353-.727-2.486-1.35-3.906-1.25z" fill="url(#t)" transform="translate(-356.685 -486.568) scale(1.31482)"/><path d="M62.918 42.35L50.815 58.656l8.07-4.66v9.32L75.02 44.68l-12.104-2.33z" fill="#ccc"/><path d="M304.22 388.2c-3.042 0-5.517 2.986-5.517 6.654.568 3.83 4.194 6.39 7.236 6.973 5.783 1.823 9.997 2.22 22.4 2.22l-20.926-14.614c-1.096-.818-2.05-1.18-3.193-1.232z" fill="url(#u)" transform="translate(-356.685 -486.568) scale(1.31482)"/><path d="M351.17 381.536c12.115 0 12.732 11.06 8.368 15.423-2.632 2.63-6.13 4.97-9.853 4.97v.375l-21.345 1.74-.124-7.083 19.048-14.176c1.353-.727 2.485-1.35 3.906-1.25z" fill="url(#v)" transform="translate(-356.685 -486.568) scale(1.31482)"/><path d="M87.102 42.35l12.104 16.306-8.07-4.66v9.32L74.998 44.68l12.104-2.33z" fill="#ccc"/><path d="M353.556 387.665c3.1 0 5.624 3.086 5.624 6.878-.578 3.96-4.275 6.604-7.375 7.208-7.86 2.513-10.813 2.295-23.465 2.295l21.96-15.106c1.118-.847 2.092-1.222 3.256-1.275z" fill="url(#w)" transform="translate(-356.685 -486.568) scale(1.31482)"/><path d="M306.03 381.533c-12.114 0-12.738 11.073-8.374 15.437 2.632 2.632 6.122 4.97 9.844 4.97v.374l20.844 1.72 21.344-1.72v-.375c3.72 0 7.21-2.338 9.843-4.97 4.365-4.364 3.74-15.437-8.374-15.437-1.42-.1-2.553.522-3.906 1.25l-18.97 14.125-18.342-14.125c-1.354-.728-2.486-1.35-3.907-1.25z" fill="url(#x)" transform="translate(-356.685 -486.568) scale(1.31482)"/></svg>
<svg height="150" width="150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><linearGradient id="s"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#e0ded2"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#cac6b2"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="r"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#6cb5ec"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#5eaeea"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="q"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#1c87d8"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#3197e4"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="i"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#a8815a"/><stop offset=".5" stop-color="#90704c"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#725433"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="j"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#473726"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#6f553a"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="a"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="d"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#97744f"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#866746"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="f"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#c7ae95"/><stop offset=".5" stop-color="#b69775"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#a57f57"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="c"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#8c6b49"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#6d5339"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="g"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#b08e69"/><stop offset=".5" stop-color="#9e7a53"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#906f4c"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="h"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#bb9d7d"/><stop offset=".5" stop-color="#ab865f"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#9f7a53"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="e"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#755a3d"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#a58057"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="m"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#b1b1b1" stop-opacity="0"/><stop offset=".5" stop-color="#b1b1b1"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#b1b1b1" stop-opacity="0"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="l"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#b3b3b3"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#9c9c9c"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="k"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#f4f4f4"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#cfcfcf"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="o"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#bdb295"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#c6bca3"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="n"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#ada07b"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#b7ab8b"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="p"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#c3ba9f"/><stop offset=".2" stop-color="#cec6b1"/><stop offset=".8" stop-color="#cec6b1"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#cdc5ae"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="b"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#ada07b"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#b7ab8b"/></linearGradient><linearGradient gradientTransform="translate(0 -164.655)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="t" x1="300.756" x2="328.975" xlink:href="#k" y1="560.903" y2="560.903"/><linearGradient gradientTransform="matrix(1.07445 0 0 1.2634 -24.445 -314.456)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="u" x1="306.859" x2="312.997" xlink:href="#l" y1="566.929" y2="559.842"/><linearGradient gradientTransform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 657.192 -164.655)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="v" x1="300.756" x2="328.975" xlink:href="#k" y1="560.903" y2="560.903"/><linearGradient gradientTransform="matrix(1.0951 0 0 1.30604 -31.23 -338.7)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="w" x1="346.751" x2="343.683" xlink:href="#l" y1="568.701" y2="559.842"/><linearGradient gradientTransform="translate(0 -164.655)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="x" x1="325.271" x2="331.408" xlink:href="#m" y1="563.386" y2="563.386"/></defs><path d="M18.74 44.95l52.153 30.014V145L18.74 114.985z" fill="#da2153"/><path d="M131.74 39.946L70.892 74.964V145l60.846-35.05z" fill="#fa2c64"/><path d="M14.456 42.673L79.916 5l55.628 32.693-64.555 37.27z" fill="#f44676"/><path d="M95.197 130.87V74.962l16.065-9.18v55.905z" fill="#ececec"/><path d="M131.51 40.07L70.88 74.946c-.027 6.222-.04 12.44.123 18.66l60.506-34.948z" fill="#9d2646" fill-opacity=".392"/><path d="M38.712 126.21V70.305l12.104 6.988V133.2z" fill="#ececec"/><path d="M18.54 44.81l.08 13.96-.08 4.546 4 2.312 48.45 27.97-.11-18.652z" fill="#66192d" fill-opacity=".392"/><path d="M135.544 37.74L70.88 74.946v13.93l.123.08 64.54-37.287z" fill="#fa376c"/><path d="M14.504 42.48V56.33L70.88 88.875v-13.93z" fill="#df2a5a"/><path d="M95.197 74.963V60.987L115.37 49.34v13.976z" fill="#ececec"/><path d="M50.816 77.293V63.316L34.676 54v13.975z" fill="#f2f2f2"/><path d="M34.677 54l64.555-37.272 16.138 9.318-64.554 37.27z" fill="#ececec"/><path d="M95.197 60.987L38.712 28.375l20.173-11.647L115.37 49.34z" fill="#f2f2f2"/><path d="M306.022 381.536c-12.115 0-12.732 11.06-8.368 15.423 2.63 2.63 6.13 4.97 9.852 4.97v.375l20.834 1.74v-7.086l-18.412-14.174c-1.353-.727-2.486-1.35-3.906-1.25z" fill="url(#t)" transform="translate(-356.685 -486.568) scale(1.31482)"/><path d="M62.918 42.35L50.815 58.656l8.07-4.66v9.32L75.02 44.68l-12.104-2.33z" fill="#ccc"/><path d="M304.22 388.2c-3.042 0-5.517 2.986-5.517 6.654.568 3.83 4.194 6.39 7.236 6.973 5.783 1.823 9.997 2.22 22.4 2.22l-20.926-14.614c-1.096-.818-2.05-1.18-3.193-1.232z" fill="url(#u)" transform="translate(-356.685 -486.568) scale(1.31482)"/><path d="M351.17 381.536c12.115 0 12.732 11.06 8.368 15.423-2.632 2.63-6.13 4.97-9.853 4.97v.375l-21.345 1.74-.124-7.083 19.048-14.176c1.353-.727 2.485-1.35 3.906-1.25z" fill="url(#v)" transform="translate(-356.685 -486.568) scale(1.31482)"/><path d="M87.102 42.35l12.104 16.306-8.07-4.66v9.32L74.998 44.68l12.104-2.33z" fill="#ccc"/><path d="M353.556 387.665c3.1 0 5.624 3.086 5.624 6.878-.578 3.96-4.275 6.604-7.375 7.208-7.86 2.513-10.813 2.295-23.465 2.295l21.96-15.106c1.118-.847 2.092-1.222 3.256-1.275z" fill="url(#w)" transform="translate(-356.685 -486.568) scale(1.31482)"/><path d="M306.03 381.533c-12.114 0-12.738 11.073-8.374 15.437 2.632 2.632 6.122 4.97 9.844 4.97v.374l20.844 1.72 21.344-1.72v-.375c3.72 0 7.21-2.338 9.843-4.97 4.365-4.364 3.74-15.437-8.374-15.437-1.42-.1-2.553.522-3.906 1.25l-18.97 14.125-18.342-14.125c-1.354-.728-2.486-1.35-3.907-1.25z" fill="url(#x)" transform="translate(-356.685 -486.568) scale(1.31482)"/></svg>
```